# Why does Hapi bomb when creating cookies?

Tags: hapi

Setting a simple cookie with Hapi.

`return h.redirect('http://localhost:3000/handle-login').state('tester', { authToken, refreshToken })`

It breaks.

```
Error: Invalid cookie value: [object Object]
    at exports.Definitions.internals.Definitions.internals.Definitions.format...
```

refreshToken and authToken are just strings.

Seems this is a common issue with Hapi
https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22Invalid+cookie+value%22

But no real solutions other than disabling some error configs in the server (sounds like a bad idea to me)

How can I make Hapi happy with simple cookie handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are storing a cookie as a JSON, you need to set the `encoding` attribute when you configure the server:

```
server.state('tester', {
    ttl: null,
    isSecure: true,
    isHttpOnly: true,
    encoding: 'base64json',
    clearInvalid: true,
    strictHeader: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to delete all the cookies from my browser and perform the request again